# Difference of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be two open sets of $\mathbf{R}^2$ (with the Euclidean topology). Is it true that if $A\setminus B$ is non-empty then there exists an open ball contained in $A\setminus B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $B = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(x,y)|x = 0\}$ (i.e. everything minus the y-axis) and $A = \mathbb{R}^2$.